# Javascript. | & and toString

Tags: javascript, operators

```
var ddd = Math.random() * 16;    
console.log((ddd & 3 | 8).toString(16));
```

Help me please. I dont understand how works this operators (| and &) and why this code returns a-f symbols?

Comment: It actually returns `8-b`: http://jsfiddle.net/SmVKt/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This picks a random real number from 0 to 15:

```
var ddd = Math.random() * 16;
```

For example, you might get 11.114714370026688.

```
ddd & 3
```

That's a bitwise AND of the result with the number 3.  The first thing that does is take the number from `ddd` and convert it to an integer, because the bitwise operators aren't defined for floating point numbers.  So in my example, it treats `ddd` as the whole number 11.

The next thing it does is perform an AND of the two numbers' binary representations.  Eleven in binary is `1011` and three is `0011`.  When you AND them together, you get a binary number that is all zeroes except where there's a 1 in *both* numbers.  Only the last two digits have 1's in both numbers, so the result is `0011`, which is again equal to decimal 3.

```
| 8
```

That does a bitwise OR of the result so far (3) with the number 8.  OR is similar to AND, but the result has 1's wherever there's a 1 in *either* number.  Since three is still `0011` in binary and eight is `1000`, the result is `1011` - which is back to decimal eleven.

In general, the above calculation sets the 8-bit (third from the right) to 1 and the 4-bit (second from the right) to 0, while leaving the other bits alone. The end result is to take your original random number, which was in the range 0-15, and turn it into one of only four numbers: 8, 9, 10, or 11. So it's a very roundabout way of generating a random number between 8 and 11, inclusive. `Math.floor(8 + Math.random()*4)` would have done the same thing in a more straightforward manner.

It then prints the result out in hexadecimal (base 16), so you get `8`, `9`, `a` (which is ten in base 16), or `b` (which is eleven).

Answer (score 5):

The expression `ddd & 2 | 8` is doing bitwise arithmetic by taking the bitwise OR operation of 8 and the bitwise AND operation of `ddd` and 2. If you don;t understand bitwise operations, you should consult [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) explaining what they are.

The code can return characters in the range a-f because you passed in a radix parameter `16` to the [`Number.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) prototype method, which means that it will display the number in hexadecimal.